# Почему  в cmd не может обработать php скрипт?

Tags: cmd, php

Вот только одна строчка:

```
exec("D:/www/iias_error/arj/arj.exe e D:/DATA/30/B0020047.C4U");
```

На браузере он обрабатывает. Здесь идёт распаковка arj архива. А вот в cmd не работает.
Может кто-нибудь знает причину?

Answer (score 1):

А откуда cmd знает как запускать скрипт? Посмотрите работу с Апачи под Win (у вас такой же сервер?) из cmd.

Comment: у меня win server 2003! запуск с cmd 
  D:\server\php\php.exe -f d:\www\iias\1.php

Comment: Сам exec не хочет обрабатывать! блин ну что может быть

Comment: Причем тут ОС? Веб-сервер IIS или "индеец"? Смотри что передаешь в cmd.